# Contourf plot colormap without normalization

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I am using a contour plot as a 2d representation of an electrode array. When the electrodes are active, the pixels on the contour plot corresponding to them have a value of 1. When the electrodes are inactive, the pixels on the contour plot corresponding to them have a value of 0. Everything else on the array (the material holding the electrodes) has a value of -1.

For visualization, I want to make a custom colormap which sets anything with a value of 1 to the color white, anything with a value of 0 to the color black, and anything else to the color grey.

I went to this stack exchange post: [matplotlib colormap without normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50975047/matplotlib-colormap-without-normalization)

Based on it, I thought it might be possible to do the following

```
def cmap(val):
            if val == 0:
                return "black"
            elif val == 1:
                return "white"
            else:
                return "grey"

plt.contourf(self.x, self.y, self.activity_meshgrid, cmap = cmap(self.activity_meshgrid))
```

However, this throws an error that this is ambiguous and that I should use .any() or .all()
When I use .any() or .all(), I realized that it won't accept a color passed to it in this way, as only colormaps are allowed values. This makes me think that it is not possible to define a colormap as a function in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from random import choices


values = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
rgb = np.array([(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)])
names = np.array(['gray', 'black', 'white'])

nx = 50
ny = 50

n = nx*ny
index = np.array(choices([0, 1, 2], k=n)).reshape((ny, nx))

f = values[index]
colors = rgb[index]
colors_flat = names[index].flatten()

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)
ax1.contourf(f, colors=colors_flat)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.imshow(colors, interpolation='none')
ax3.matshow(colors)
```

The figure will be like this (similar):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Other option:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from random import choices

nx = 50
ny = 50

# Just a dummy data array with -1; 0 and 1.
f = np.array(choices([-1, 0, 1], k=nx*ny)).reshape((ny, nx))

i_zero = np.where(f==0)
i_one = np.where(f==1)
i_neg_one = np.where(f==-1)

colors_name = np.empty((ny, nx), dtype='<U20')
colors_name[i_zero] = 'black'
colors_name[i_one] = 'white'
colors_name[i_neg_one] = 'gray'
colors_flat = colors_name.flatten()

colors_rgb = np.zeros((ny, nx, 3))
colors_rgb[i_zero] = (0, 0, 0)
colors_rgb[i_one] = (1, 1, 1)
colors_rgb[i_neg_one] = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)
ax1.contourf(f, colors=colors_flat)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.imshow(colors_rgb, interpolation='none')
ax3.matshow(colors_rgb)
```